# Connection to an online mysql database using odbc , getting permission denied error on Accessing Tables

Tags: .net, mysql, permissions, odbc, permission-denied

```
[mysqld-4.1.22-standard]SELECT command denied to user 

'mydb_user'@'123.xxx.xxx.xxx' for table 'products'
```

I have added my PC from which am accessing the online database -- '123.xxx.xxx.xxx' --- in the REMOTE HOSTS also, do i need to give permission separately for this IP on the database? But how?

I have given all privileges to the database user: mydb_user by adding this user into the database from the cpanel of my website and granting him all the permissions.

I am able to connect to the database successfully, but when i pass a query : SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS,  then it gives the above mentioned error.

Even if am connected to the database using THE MAIN LOGIN (i.e. THE CREDENTIALS WHICH I USE TO LOG INTO THE CPANEL) , then also , it gives the same error............Please help......!!!!!

Am connecting to the online mysql database of my website from a local C# WINFORM .NET APPLICATION which uses :

```
OdbcConnection addprodConn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};
uid=mydb_user;password=********;server=www.mywebsite.com;database=mydb;port=3306");
```

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct username and password

Comment: @Ibu : yes sir, it connects, using these id and passwords, but , when i  try to select records , then it gives error

Comment: @Ibu   :  my local PC, from which am accessing the online mysql database, has an IP-123.xxx.xxx.xxx , do i need to give permission for this PARTICULAR IP  on the database?

Comment: how about you connect to your local db using these credentials.I may be wrong, but i dont think you can connect to your online db from your local computer to serve pages. try setting up your databse on your local machine

Comment: no sir, i have one more table "logins" on my online database, and on Selecting data from that table does not gives any error.........then why is this products table irritating me?

Answer (score 1):

I can't really assume a solution to your problem, but you can try to debug it:

See what are the priviledges of `mydb_user` on the database. Use this sql statement

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'mydb_user'@'localhost'; // or whatever your db host is
```

Also i recommend using a utility tool like [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html) for working with your testing.

Comment: sir, when i log in to phpmyadmin of my website, by cpanel, then on running this query : select * from products ---i get this error:--Access denied for user 'mydb_user'@'localhost' to database 'mydb\_inventory

Comment: Your database name is `mydb_inventory`, in your code above you are trying to connect to `mydb` i am pretty sure that is the issue